# Error Failure delivering result when choosing second image from Gallery

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to complete my first sample application with the list of items. With purpose to have own image for each item in the list I have found on stackoverflow the following code:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();

        main_datasource.pic.setPicturePath(picturePath);
    }
}
```

It works great and I can choose image but only once. 
When I try to choose second time the following error pops up:

```
11:14:41.472    1212    example.CustomAdapter   ERROR   AndroidRuntime  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11:14:41.472    1212    example.CustomAdapter   ERROR   AndroidRuntime  java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://media/external/images/media/2 }} to activity {example.CustomAdapter/example.CustomAdapter.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11:14:41.472    1212    example.CustomAdapter   ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2532)
11:14:41.472    1212    example.CustomAdapter   ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:2574)
11:14:41.472    1212    example.CustomAdapter   ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:117)
11:14:41.472    1212    example.CustomAdapter   ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:961)
11:14:41.472    1212    example.CustomAdapter   ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11:14:41.472    1212    example.CustomAdapter   ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11:14:41.472    1212    example.CustomAdapter   ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
11:14:41.472    1212    example.CustomAdapter   ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11:14:41.472    1212    example.CustomAdapter   ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11:14:41.472    1212    example.CustomAdapter   ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
11:14:41.472    1212    example.CustomAdapter   ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
11:14:41.472    1212    example.CustomAdapter   ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11:14:41.472    1212    example.CustomAdapter   ERROR   AndroidRuntime  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11:14:41.472    1212    example.CustomAdapter   ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at example.CustomAdapter.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:303)
11:14:41.472    1212    example.CustomAdapter   ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3908)
11:14:41.472    1212    example.CustomAdapter   ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2528)
11:14:41.472    1212    example.CustomAdapter   ERROR   AndroidRuntime      ... 11 more
```

Since I am a new guy in Android could you please help me to update this code in way when I will be able to choose images. It will be also very useful if someone will explain me how this code works.

Comment: Did you figure this out?  I'm having the same issue.